# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).progressBar is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a **wordpress** website running the Lydia template. Recently I have bought and installed the **Gmedia** plugin to display a nice gallery called AlbumsView 2.

The problem is that the gallery is not showing up on the page and instead on the **console** I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).progressBar is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js?ver=5.3.2:486)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

No errors or red calls on the **Network** tab (developer console).

I did some research on the web and apparently the order in which the jQuery is imported by the scripts might be the cause.

This is the config where all the scripts are called. I have tried switching positions, removing them one by one but nothing works.

[image]

I have also tried to delete the function that is called on line 486 from the error message but then another console error appears complaining about other function and it goes on and on like this.

Here is the [link](http://hosting1996765.online.pro/autoinstalator/wordpress/index.php/gmedia-gallery/test/) to my gallery so you can see the error yourself.

I am a java developer so my wordpress expertise is quite limited, can someone guide me to solve this nightmare?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The plugin is referencing a method from JQuery UI but you haven't included it.

Comment: @EternalHour you are right, however after adding the jquery UI import for progressbar, the error persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you add JQuery UI before the plugin in your HTML, possibly directly after JQuery. Take a look at the documentation at: https://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/ and also add any dependencies including the CSS.